# Doesn't have a 'Release file' when upade Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, ubuntu-18.04, linux-terminal

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu bionic 
Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore 
disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration 
details.
```

My version:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
```

Hey,

I've got a message not so long ago about updating my system which couldn't finish because of this error. Not sure exactly what this update for and how normally I should get updates. would be happy for some general explanation.

Big thanks,

Niv

Comment: `apt-get update --allow-unauthenticated` would bypass force the upgrade.  However, the upgrade is blocked, for a good reason so I would not recommend forcing the upgrade.  Instead I would run `rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cooperjona-ubuntu-nitrotasks-bionic.list`

Comment: Please see the answer below, "sudo potato" said it's connected to node.js installation probably. What do you think?

Comment: There is a reason I also suggested you remove the repository instead of forcefully allowing the updates to happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not Ubuntu that's having an issue updating, it looks like it's `'http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu bionic Release'`. Google search finds [this](https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/ubuntu/node.js/). It looks like you downloaded that repository to your machine, but you can't update it because there is no release file. Are you using it? If not, trying removing it and then re-update your OS.

You can remove the ppa through either the GUI or terminal.

**Option 1 - GUI Method:**

Step 1:
Go to Unity dash (by pressing the super or Windows key) and search for Software Sources:

[image: Unity dash]

Step 2:
In the Software Sources, go to Other Software tab and choose the desire PPA from the list. Afterwards click on Remove to remove it:

[image: Delete PPA]

**Option 2 - Remove PPA Using apt in terminal:**

`sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:PPA_Name/ppa`

[Source!](https://itsfoss.com/how-to-remove-or-delete-ppas-quick-tip/)

Comment: Wow didn't even notice it was related to node.js installation. I just installed this framework and didn't even use it. How do I remove it from my Ubuntu OS?

Comment: It is possible to force the update, but it's blocked for a valid reason. If you're not using whatever was in that repository, I'd recommend removing it.

Feel free to upvote/select as answer if I've helped.

Comment: I've updated my answer with instructions on removing it.

Comment: It was very helpful but not sure if I should remove what gonna be part of my ongoing learning. I have to use it soon. In anycase, I updated the nod.js so hopefully it will be fine. Really thanks for helping until now mate appreciate that, I saved your guide for the future.

Comment: No problem. Please select my answer as correct if I've helped.

Comment: Should all the softwares be marked 'V' like yours in the Software Sources in Ubuntu?

Comment: Not necessarily. Depends on what software you're using.

Comment: So you just recommend removing and try to update all the system again basically? Are you sure it's the right file to remove?

Comment: If the text you included in your OP is correct, then yes.